# How to fix that OpenCL freezes?

Tags: c++, linux, opencl

I'm trying to detect blinking pixels. I've written the code in C++ first but I realized, that a CPU is not suitable for it. So I found the OpenCL library. I've never used it before.
Besides, I haven't found a good documentation for OpenCL.

OpenCLHelper.cpp

```
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>


cl::Program CreateProgram(const std::string& fileName) {


    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

    auto platform = platforms.front();
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);

    auto device = devices.front();

    std::ifstream file(fileName);
    std::string src(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    cl::Program::Sources sources(1, std::make_pair(src.c_str(), src.length()+1));

    cl::Context context(device);

    cl::Program program(context, sources);

    std::cout << program.build("-cl-std=CL1.2") << std::endl;
    return program;
}
```

main.cpp (not the whole code of the file)

```
cl::Context context = program.getInfo<CL_PROGRAM_CONTEXT>();
vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
cl::Device device = devices.front();

unsigned char* shootFrame(unsigned char *data) {

    unsigned char* frequencyImage = new unsigned char[pixelsPerFrame];
    strcopy(data, frequencyImage);


        cl_int err = 0;
        cl::Buffer inBuf(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(unsigned char) * pixelsPerFrame * equalxFramesAtTheSameTime, lastFrames, &err);
        cout << err << endl;

        cl::Buffer outBuf(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY, sizeof(unsigned char) * pixelsPerFrame, nullptr, &err);

        cl::Buffer var1(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int), &isLightOn, &err);cout << err << endl;

//I creates variables, because I can't use #define in there
        int equalxFramesAtTheSameTime2 = equalxFramesAtTheSameTime;
        cl::Buffer var2(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int), &equalxFramesAtTheSameTime2, &err);cout << err << endl;
        int thresholdPixel2 = thresholdPixel;
        cl::Buffer var3(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int), &thresholdPixel2, &err);cout << err << endl;
        int ppf = pixelsPerFrame;
        cl::Buffer var4(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int), &ppf, &err);cout << err << endl;

        cl::Buffer var5(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int), &currentFrameID, &err);cout << err << endl;

        cl::Kernel kernel(program, "ProcessImage"); cout << err << endl;

        err = kernel.setArg(0, var1); cout << err << endl;
        err = kernel.setArg(1, var2); cout << err << endl;
        err = kernel.setArg(2, var3); cout << err << endl;
        err = kernel.setArg(3, var4); cout << err << endl;
        err = kernel.setArg(4, var5); cout << err << endl;
        err = kernel.setArg(5, inBuf); cout << err << endl;
        err = kernel.setArg(6, outBuf); cout << err << endl;


        cl::CommandQueue queue(context, device);

        err = queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(pixelsPerFrame)); cout << err << endl;

        err = queue.enqueueReadBuffer(outBuf, CL_FALSE, 0, sizeof(unsigned char) * pixelsPerFrame, done); cout << err << endl;

        cout << "done: " << queue.finish() << endl;

        return getXYfromRawImage(done, frequencyImage, updown, leftright);
}
```

ProcessImage.cl

```
__kernel void ProcessImage(const int isLightOn, const int frameSize, const int thresholdPixel, const int pixelsPerFrame, const int currentFrameID, __global unsigned char* lastFrames, __global unsigned char* outData) {
    int isBegin = 1;

    bool mustBrightNow = !isLightOn;

    int lastPixel = 0;

    int isWrongPixel = 0;


    for (int i=currentFrameID; i<frameSize + currentFrameID; i++) {

        int i2 = i;

        if(i >= frameSize) {
            i2 = i2 - frameSize;
        }       

        int id = (i2 * pixelsPerFrame) + get_global_id(0);

        if (isBegin == 1) {
            lastPixel = (int) lastFrames[ id ];
            isBegin = 0;

        } else {
            int currentPixel = (int) lastFrames[ id ];

            if (mustBrightNow == false) {
                if (currentPixel + thresholdPixel < lastPixel) {
                    mustBrightNow = true;
                } else {
                    isWrongPixel = 0; //It freezes when I write '1' 
instead of '0'

                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (currentPixel - thresholdPixel > lastPixel) {
                    mustBrightNow = false;
                } else {
                    isWrongPixel = 0; //Also it freezes when I write '1'. And it doesn't matter if is an integer or a boolean.

                    break;
                }
            }

            lastPixel = currentPixel;
        }

    }
    if (isWrongPixel == 0) {
        outData[get_global_id(0)] = (uchar) (0);
    } else {
        outData[get_global_id(0)] = (uchar) (1);
    }

}
```

On all `cout` I get `0`. So "no" noticeable errors.

I know, that some parts of the code aren't optimized, but it should work.

If you want to now, the `unsigned char* lastFrames` is built like for every pixel a char (monochrome). So its size is 20 million (Width x Height x previous frames). So it has multiple frames and I can compare different frames in OpenCL.

So what could that be?

- Is there a problem, that not the main thread starts the kernel but
  the pthread_t.
- And OpenCL freezes mostly at the 146th frame or randomly. Maybe a
  mistake in memory?
- And it only freezes when I write in `isWrongPixel` `1` or
  `true`.
- And when I write `0` or `false` it will work, but I need a
  boolean.
- And I haven't tried more than 500 frames in a run.

So what am I doing wrong ?

I know that my grammar is not completely correct..

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'freeze'? Like `enqueNDRangeKernel` doesn't return? How long does it take before the freeze happens? How did you get  the 146 frame? There is usually a hard limit on maximum runtime, my GPU kills any kernel after few seconds. Make sure that `pixelsPerFrame` is smaller than `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES` and `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE`. Obtained by `clGetDeviceInfo`. Or programs like GPU-Z can show you that too. I did not spot any other mistakes regarding OpenCL calls nor any in the kernel. 1/2

Comment: But if I understand the kernel correctly then `isWrongPixel` directly determines the output and if you never change it from 0 then the loop has no effect and compiler is free to remove the whole loop and directly set output to zero. Then if you change it to 1 it must execute the loop and may crash because of something inside( although I do not see any overflow mistakes) or it might get killed by the driver as I stated above. Obviously I am not sure if the compiler is capable of that, but I don't think it's impossible.

Comment: @Quimby With freeze I mean, that `enqueNDRangeKernel` doesn't return. I've found also out, that my GPU is not recognized but my CPU. CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES is 16,777,216 and  CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE is 256 (`pixelsPerFrame` is 2,457,600, but `lastFrames` is 19,660,800). And I think it's not too bad, that I can't use my GPU because I want to run the code on a cheap single board computer (about 100$). I think my Intel i7-6700K would be faster. And I know it will work with my GTX 1070 Ti.

Comment: @Quimby I also have read, that there are Image support.
Max size for 1D images from buffer would be 268,434,944 pixels,
Max 2D image size 16,384x16,384 pixels or
Max 3D image size 16,384x16,384x2,048 pixels for my CPU. But I don't know how to use it

Comment: Yes, there are Images and the Image3D could be used here. Can you please measure if there is a time difference in execution when you put '1' there and when you don't? For some big values that don't freeze yet. I do think the compiler optimized the loop as I said earlier. Both gcc and clang do ( [link](https://godbolt.org/z/NTBfM0) )and Intel uses LLVM based compiler too. Putting begin&end stopwatch from enqueue to clFinish should be enough. If there's a difference I will write you an answer that uses Image3D because I cannot fit it in a comment and perhaps it will also solve freezes.

Comment: @Quimby when I set it to '0', about 0.97294ms
and when I set it to '1' it takes about 1.37452ms. I measured it behind enqueueNDRangeKernel and after finish().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on the discussion from comments.

Here's an example how to use Images:

```
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <vector>

std::vector<cl::Platform> clPlatforms;
cl::Platform::get(&clPlatforms);

// TODO Set correctly
cl::Device chosenDevice;
bool first = true;
for (auto &&platform : clPlatforms) {
    std::vector<cl::Device> clDevices;
    platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &clDevices);

    if (first) { // REMOVE
        chosenDevice = clDevices[0];
        first = false;
    }

    std::cout << platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>()<<'\n';
    for (auto &&device : clDevices) {
        std::cout << device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()<<'\n';
    }
}

cl::Context context{chosenDevice};
// Possible values
// https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/cl_image_format.html
cl::ImageFormat format{ CL_R, CL_UNSIGNED_INT8};

std::size_t imageWidth = 640;
std::size_t imageHeight = 480;
std::size_t numFrames = 128;
// Fill as sequences of rows for each 2D
std::uint8_t
    *input = new std::uint8_t[imageWidth * imageHeight * numFrames];

std::size_t i = 0;
for (std::size_t frameI = 0; frameI < numFrames; ++frameI)
    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < imageHeight; ++y)
        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < imageWidth; ++x)
            input[i++] = 0; // INIT

// Zeroes specify data format, see
// https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateImage3D.html
// Note that images cannot be both read and write
cl::Image3D
    inImage{context,
            CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_NO_ACCESS | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
            format,
            imageWidth,
            imageHeight,
            numFrames,
            0,
            0,
            input,
            nullptr};
cl::Image2D outImage{context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY,
                     format, imageWidth, imageHeight};

std::string source = "PASTE SOURCE HERE";
cl::Program program(context, source);
program.build("-cl-std=CL1.2");

cl::Kernel kernel(program, "ProcessImage");
kernel.setArg(0, (int)0);
kernel.setArg(1, (int)numFrames);
int thresholdPixel = 10; // SET
kernel.setArg(2, (int)thresholdPixel);
kernel.setArg(3, (int)(imageWidth * imageHeight));
int currentFrameID = 12; // SET
kernel.setArg(4, (int)currentFrameID);
kernel.setArg(5, inImage);
kernel.setArg(6, outImage);
cl::CommandQueue queue(context, chosenDevice);
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange,
                           cl::NDRange(imageWidth, imageHeight));

std::uint8_t *output = new std::uint8_t[imageWidth * imageHeight];
// See
// https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueReadImage.html
cl::size_t<3> region;
region[0] = imageWidth;
region[1] = imageHeight;
region[2] = 1;
//Might as well block if the next call would be clFinish anyway.
queue.enqueueReadImage(outImage, true, cl::size_t<3>(), region, 0, 0,
                       output);
```

The kernel source:

```
__kernel void ProcessImage(const int isLightOn, const int frameSize, const int thresholdPixel, const int pixelsPerFrame, const int currentFrameID, read_only image3d_t lastFrames, write_only image2d_t outData) {
    int isBegin = 1;
    bool mustBrightNow = !isLightOn;
    int lastPixel = 0;
    int isWrongPixel = 0;

    for (int i=currentFrameID; i<frameSize + currentFrameID; i++) {
        int i2 = i;

        if(i >= frameSize) {
            i2 = i2 - frameSize;
        }       

        int pixValue = (int)read_imageui(lastFrames,(int4)(get_global_id(0),get_global_id(1),i2,0)).x;
        if (isBegin == 1) {
            lastPixel = pixValue;
            isBegin = 0;
        } else {
            int currentPixel = pixValue;

            if (mustBrightNow == false) {
                if (currentPixel + thresholdPixel < lastPixel) {
                    mustBrightNow = true;
                } else {
                    isWrongPixel = 1; 
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if (currentPixel - thresholdPixel > lastPixel) {
                    mustBrightNow = false;
                } else {
                    isWrongPixel = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            lastPixel = currentPixel;
        }
    }
    write_imageui(outData,(int2)(get_global_id(0),get_global_id(1)),(uint4)(isWrongPixel,0,0,0));
}
```

I was able to run this code both on my 1050TI, Intel 7700HQ and Intel 630HD without freezes, I hope you will to :)

I replaced buffers with images, and also made this task "2D" which is reflected in `enqueueNDRangeKernel`. The kernel does exactly the same thing, but it makes indexing images more natural. I was not sure if you are aware of multiple platforms, which might allow you to use your GPU. It should only need up-to-date drivers, nothing else for it to show up in platforms and devices. There's no need to create buffers for `const` variables, just use correct types in `kernel.setArg` template function.

So try it :)

Comment: OMG, thank you so much! Now it runs perfect. But one question, when I put this in a `while true` loop. Do I need to compile the code once or every run ?

Comment: Create all OpenCL objects at the beginning and then only call enqueueXXX functions as many times as you want.